# Name of a kids sci-fi story about living shadows controlling their owners?

Tags: story-identification

I read a great kids sci-fi story when I was young about sentient shadows that took over the lives of their owners. Basically an invasion / body snatcher plot where the bodysnatchers were peoples shadows.

It may have been by Nicholas Fisk or similar, and I think it was a story in a collection of short stories, though I am not positive of these details.

I've had a hunt on the internet for 'sentient shadows', 'living shadows', 'shadows taking over the earth', but haven't turned it up yet.

This story scared me silly when I was young, and I would love to read it again. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever, but maybe it helps other people to answer your question if you could narrow the time of reading. When exactly did you read it? Was it an old book by then already or brand new?

Comment: Ah, that would be sensible: I would have read it sometime around 1982. It was a library book so I don't recall if it was old, but my gut feel is that it would have been written sometime in the 70's or very early 80's. It was definitely in the children's section of the library, so not an adult story.

Comment: I read the title and immediately thought of Garth Nix's The Seventh Tower series, but it doesn't fit the other details.

Comment: Thank you, I had a look at Garth Nix, and I'm fairly sure it's not the one. The shadow story was a horror sci fi story really - definitely quite disturbing.